# Performance problems with list.files

Tags: r, shell, find

I am trying to retrieve files from 3 network drives using `list.files` and it takes for ever. When I am using `find` in the shell it returns all results in less then 15 seconds.

```
system.time(
  jnk <- list.files(c("/Volumes/massspec", "/Volumes/massspec2", "/Volumes/massspec3"), 
                    pattern='_MA_.*_HeLa_', 
                    recursive=TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.567   6.381 309.500
```

Here is the equivalent shell command.

```
time find /Volumes/masssp* -name *_MA_*_HeLa_*
# real  0m13.776s
# user  0m0.361s
# sys   0m0.620s
```

I need a solution which works on Windows and Unix systems. Has anyone a good idea? The network drives have altogether about 120,000 files but about 16TB. So not much files but very huge ones.

Comment: What does prevent you to do a system call to `find` to build the list ? There's is portable versions of find for windows. Packaginf it with your script should not be a real problem.

Comment: I was hoping there is a way around it, but unfortunately, I have to use this solution, yes...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, I wrote a little R function which should work on Windows and Unix...

```
quickFileSearch <- function(path, pattern) {
  switch (.Platform$OS.type,
          unix={
            paths <- paste(path, collapse=' ')
            command <- paste('find', paths, '-name', pattern)
            system(command, intern=TRUE)
          },
          windows={
            paths <- paste(file.path(path, pattern, 
                                     fsep='\\'),
                           collapse=' ')
            command <- paste('dir', paths, '/b /s /a-d')
            shell(command, intern=TRUE)}
  )
}
```

The whole thing is not much tested yet but it is working for my purpose.

Comment: Side note: you'll have a problem with /b on systems where the short filenames is disabled (IIRC since win8 by default on fresh install, keep the old behavior on updates as it is a property of the NTFS file system)

Comment: Actually, I have almost no experience with windows and specially not with the `dir` command. I just used google and tested on one specific machine and it seems to work. So I don't understand your comment :-)

Comment: Starting from windows7 short filenames could be disabled, in this case the /b switch of dir won't make any change and you'll end up with long filenames: "longfilenamesover8chars.txt" become "longfi~1.txt" in shortname. the /b switch may (or not) return your the short name and break your code. You just need to be carefull about it.

Comment: @Tensibai so which switch would you suggest though?

Comment: Not using /b and using filenames without spaces. My comment is just a warning for future readers.