# Listing files quickly using system calls

Tags: r

I'm trying to list a lot of files matching a pattern, that I can make a list of and later `lapply`. In R it's quite slow with `list.files`, but [digging around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743174/performance-problems-with-list-files) I found that

```
system(find "\path\" -name "pattern")
```

makes it about 5 times faster.

The problem is that the above only works in the terminal, whereas in R it only returns a "list of 1"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `system` needs the command to be a single character string, i.e. `system("find 'path' -name 'pattern'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really put a quote around the entire command, also in case you want to save the output into an R object/vector, you may use an option called **intern** with "TRUE" value like below:

```
system('find "/Users/pradeepkumar" -name "*.R"',intern=T)
```

**Output received:**

```
> system('find "/Users/pradeepkumar" -name "*.R"',intern=T)
 [1] "/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/company doc/g/code/SIPC-10.R"                                                                                                                 
 [2] "/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/company doc/g/code/SIPC-2.R"                                                                                                                  
 [3] "/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/company doc/g/code/SIPC-3.R"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! ...However, it only works if I put in the full names. Using defined variables (for a general function) breaks it, e.g. `system('find my_path -name my_pattern', intern = TRUE)`. I'm not sure how to manage the single quotes. Perhaps some `paste()` trick?.

Comment: You can use : `x <-"*.R" `;
`system(sprintf('find "/Users/pradeepkumar" -name "%s"', x))`

Comment: Okay, now I've managed to list every file with the command `raw_list <- system(sprintf('find "%s" -name "%s"',
                           path,
                           pattern,
                           intern = TRUE))`.

R will list a huge number of files, but I'm unable to store all these in any format. Other people's solution has been to use `list.files()`, but that kind of puts me back at square one.

Comment: Edit to above. It works. I had just placed `intern = TRUE` in the wrong bracket.

Comment: @komodovaran_ congratulations, happy for you, glad its woked